# Understanding list `pop index out of range`

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to arrange a list generated in ascending order.

Using `remove` in my while loop works. But if I use `pop` I keep getting an IndexError: Pop index out of range.

I also tried increasing the length of `values` list when the last iteration will be carried out; to `while len(values) > 1` and I'm still getting the same error.

Can anyone please explain why I keep getting this error when using pop but not when using remove?

```
#import randrange
from random import randrange

#generate a list of values
values = []
for i in range(1, 10):
   values.append(randrange(1, 10))
print(values)

#initiate list for keeping minimum values
new_values = []

#define how least value would be determined
while len(values) > 0 :
   new_values.append(min(values))
   values.pop(min(values))


print(new_values)
```

Comment: That's because `min(values)` will return the result of the smallest number found in the list, not the length of the list. So you could end up with a number that is `4` on a list that's only size of `1`, for instance `values = [4]` and then `values.pop(min(values))` would generate these kinds of issues. You're probably looking for `values.pop(len(values))`?

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to do. Please take a read on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and help us to help you

Comment: Did you try checking each time through the loop, for example, what `min(values)` is equal to, and what is in `new_values` before and after?

Answer (score 0):

You are providing direct values to pop while writing `values.pop(min(values))`, instead you have to provide the index position.

Answer (score 0):

pop takes an *index* into the list, not a value present in the list. See [list.pop([i])](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Also see the docs on [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: Right - from the docs directly above pop: "Remove the first item from the list _whose value is equal to x_. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item."

Answer (score 0):

*You need to pass the **index** to `pop` not the value you want to remove*
[(`list.pop` docs)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html)

*If you really **must use** `pop`* you can use `numpy.argmin` to get index of minimum value like this:

```
import numpy as np
new_values = []

#define how least value would be determined
while len(values) > 0 :
    new_values.append(min(values))
    values.pop(np.argmin(values))
```

But if you are ***just sorting*** a list why not use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in function?

```
new_values = sorted(values)
```

Comment: New to programming, I'm trying to understand how loops work and when to use what type of loop.

Comment: @Nnaobi that's cool! Hope I have helped you somehow then... Good luck on your learnings

Comment: Numpy it total overkill for this

Comment: There is no overkill If you are just playing around for learning